# How to avoid to subscribe to a Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

So, I have a form.
I want to react to every input change, not on blur, not on submit.
I don't want to add (change) listeners to every input.

Currently I am doing:
`this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(...);`
Problem solved!

Well, sure, but here comes my question… what if I don't want to have to use `subscribe` either? I'm using the `async` pipe everywhere to avoid having to do that. How do I avoid it in this case?

I tried to pass the valueChanges on the Output to the parent component…

```
Output() formChanges: Observable<FormInterface>;

constructor() {
  this.formChanges = this.form.valueChanges;
}
```

Which resulted in:
`ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`
A.k.a. crashing the application.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does "react" mean? What do you want to do when the value changes. And why would you want to avoid subscribing to an observable? There is nothing wrong with that. That's what the async pipe does, BTW. That's what observables are for.

Comment: you shouldn't be blindly trying to avoid subscribing. The async pipe is preferable in many cases but not all. Sometimes subscribing is correct. passing valueChanges to an output is one of those cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the better way would be to subscribe to the `valueChanges` and then emmit event with the required information, instead of doing it this way which you chose.